# what kind of error (or whatever it is) is this "<function 'nameOfFunction' at 0x0000011D203BE0>" in python?

Tags: python, function

I've only recently started with python so I'm not entirely certain what to do. I've tried renaming the function and the dictionary. Rearranged the formatting a buy but still nothing. And I don't know what to do and I feel so frustrated (to the point of wanting to stop programming altogether). If anyone can help, please do.

Note: the bit that starts with 0x00000 in my question changes with every run.

```
def translate(word):
    translate = " "

    for letter in word:
        if letter.lower() in translations.keys():
            if letter.islower():
                translation += translations.get(letter)
            else:
                translation += translations.get(letter.lower()).capitalise()
         else:
             translation += letter
    return translate

print(translate (input("Enter a phrase: ")
```

Comment: This is not an error.  This is what it looks like when you print a function. e.g. `def foo: pass` then `print(foo)` Note, the code you provided actually doesn't even compile, so we can only guess at what is actually going on. But I'll note, you `return translate` from within the `translate` function, although, that should just be what `translate = " "` has at that moment, but in general, you shouldn't shadow the function name with a local variable. I think what's actually going on is that you *actually* have `translation = " "`, but return `translate`, which would just be the function object

Comment: In **any** case, for debugging questions, you must **always** provide a [mcve]

Comment: Ah, okay, I see, thanks. 

It's probably not compiling because I didn't add the dictionary I have in the code. Originally I had ```return translate``` but when I realised it might've been a problem with the return statement, I changed it to ```return translation``` and it worked

Here's the full project on github which works fine now: https://github.com/kmmalpha/English-to-Shupekai-Translator

Answer (score 0):

Just like @juanpa-arrivillaga wrote.
You just got the naming of your return variable wrong.
So just use "translation".
The correct code should look like this:

```
def translate(word):
    translation = " "
    for letter in word:
        if letter.lower() in translations.keys():
            if letter.islower():
                translation += translations.get(letter)
            else:
                translation += translations.get(letter.lower()).capitalise()
        else:
             translation += letter
    return translation

print(translate (input("Enter a phrase: ")))
```